# How to align the output?

Tags: java, arff

Could someone please help me with this. I dont know how to align this. I would appreciate your help. And could you teach me the appropriate to code this.. thanks!

Current Code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Arff{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        File TextFile = new File("weather.nominal.arff");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(TextFile);

        while(reader.hasNextLine()){
            String text = reader.nextLine();
            String[] SplitData = text.split(" ");

            if(SplitData[0].equals("@relation")){
                System.out.println(SplitData[1]);
                System.out.println();
            }
            if(SplitData[0].equals("@attribute")){
                System.out.print(SplitData[1]+" ");
            }

            if(!SplitData[0].equals("@data") && !SplitData[0].equals("@attribute") && !SplitData[0].equals("@relation")){
                System.out.println(SplitData[0].replace(',', ' '));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

weather.symbolic.arff

```
    @relation weather.symbolic 
    @attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
    @attribute temperature {hot, mild, cool}
    @attribute humidity {high, normal}
    @attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
    @attribute play {yes, no}

    @data
    sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no
    sunny,hot,high,TRUE,no
    overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes
    rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes
    rainy,cool,normal,FALSE,yes
    rainy,cool,normal,TRUE,no
    overcast,cool,normal,TRUE,yes
    sunny,mild,high,FALSE,no
    sunny,cool,normal,FALSE,yes
    rainy,mild,normal,FALSE,yes
    sunny,mild,normal,TRUE,yes
    overcast,mild,high,TRUE,yes
    overcast,hot,normal,FALSE,yes
    rainy,mild,high,TRUE,no
```

Current output:

```
weather.symbolic

outlook temperature humidity windy play
sunny hot high FALSE no
sunny hot high TRUE no
overcast hot high FALSE yes
rainy mild high FALSE yes
rainy cool normal FALSE yes
rainy cool normal TRUE no
overcast cool normal TRUE yes
sunny mild high FALSE no
sunny cool normal FALSE yes
rainy mild normal FALSE yes
sunny mild normal TRUE yes
overcast mild high TRUE yes
overcast hot normal FALSE yes
rainy mild high TRUE no
```

preferred output:

```
weather.symbolic

outlook     temperature humidity    windy   play

sunny       hot         high        FALSE   no
sunny       hot         high        TRUE    no
overcast    hot         high        FALSE   yes
rainy       mild        high        FALSE   yes
rainy       cool        normal      FALSE   yes
rainy       cool        normal      TRUE    no
overcast    cool        normal      TRUE    yes
sunny       mild        high        FALSE   no
sunny       cool        normal      FALSE   yes
rainy       mild        normal      FALSE   yes
sunny       mild        normal      TRUE    yes
overcast    mild        high        TRUE    yes
overcast    hot         normal      FALSE   yes
rainy       mild        high        TRUE    no
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should use special characters**

You have to use `\t` between columns

**Then your should modify as follows.**

```
        if (!SplitData[0].equals("@data") && !SplitData[0].equals("@attribute") && !SplitData[0].equals("@relation")) {
            System.out.println(SplitData[0].replace(',', '\t'));
        }
```

**Additionally you should know following this regarding special characters of java.**

As same as other programming languages such c++,c, c# there are several special characters in java. Each of them and their usage as follows.

- `\'` - Single quotation mark
- `\"` - Double quotation mark
- `\\` - Backslash
- `\t` - Tab
- `\b` - Backspace
- `\r` - Carriage return
- `\f` - Formfeed
- `\n` - Newline

Comment: how to add more \t? like this  System.out.println(SplitData[0].replace(',', '\t\t'));

Comment: you corect, you have to do i as `\t\t` or more if needed.

Comment: you can use as `\t` since it is a single character. but `\t\t` is two characters. So you cannot use in single quotation marks. You have to use double quotation marks as `"\t\t"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91042/discussion-between-channa-jayamuni-and-soyan).